# SQL create a new record when none was found

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking for a possibility to search for an specific record. If none was found, a new one should be created and displayed.

This is what I got so far:

```
DECLARE @Anzahl int

Select @Anzahl = COUNT(tbl_Kommentare.FID_Typ) AS Zahl FROM tbl_Kommentare WHERE ((tbl_Kommentare.FID_Typ)=99) AND ((tbl_Kommentare.FID_Sprache)=1)

IF (@Anzahl = 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tbl_Kommentare (FID_Typ, FID_Sprache) VALUES (99, 1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT tbl_Kommentare.FID_Typ FROM tbl_Kommentare WHERE (((tbl_Kommentare.FID_Typ)=99) AND ((tbl_Kommentare.FID_Sprache)=1)))
END
```

I get this Notification:

> Invalid sql-statement 'delete' 'insert' 'select' or 'update' expected

What is the Problem?

Comment: Try removingn `BEGIN`, `END` and then go.

Comment: If you're putting this type of SQL in to Access that might be your problem. Access doesn't process all the same statements that SQL Server can.

Comment: How and where are you executing this code? Which line produces the error?

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl this doesn't work. :-/

Comment: @Andre I am executing this in a normal access query which I tried to change to my needs. Maybe this is the problem? The error is oproduced by the first line.

Comment: This is the issue. Access doesn't recognise your first `DECLARE` statement because Access isn't designed to run such things; essentially the error message is Access telling you that it was expecting an SQL statement that started with `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT` or `UPDATE`. Unfortunately `DECLARE` is a T-Sql statement so won't work in Access. See http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/declare_vars.php

Answer (score 1):

You can't run T-SQL in Access, and you could do it quite differently.

In the form, set the *DefaultValue* property of the two fields to 99 and 1.

Then, in your form, use *DCount* to look up the value:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("FID_Typ", "tbl_Kommentare", "[FID_Typ]=99 AND [FID_Sprache]=1")) Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord acActiveDataObject, Me.Name, acNewRec 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to place a `;` at  the end of each of your statements. Do so at the end of `select @....... );`, at the end of `INSERT INTO tbl...... );`, and ad the end of `SELECT tbl_kom....);`.

Also, you have an extra parenthesis in your last `SELECT....` statement. Change this:

```
(((tbl_Kommentare.FID_Typ)=99) AND ((tbl_Kommentare.FID_Sprache)=1)))
```

to this:

```
(((tbl_Kommentare.FID_Typ)=99) AND ((tbl_Kommentare.FID_Sprache)=1));
```

let me know if those corrections fixed the problem.